# How to use icon images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

In my travels I often examine the rendered HTML, CSS, and Javascript source of the sites I visit. There is one technique I have seen used all over that still mystifies me. I often find images like this one:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](http://d297h9he240fqh.cloudfront.net/cache-588bcdd93/images/compass/icon-sprite.png))</sub>

It is filled with icons, yet the usage of this image on the site limits the image to only one of the icons within the large image at a time. They essentially appear to use the same image for a large number of icons.

If I understand correctly then this would greatly help when it comes to the loading and caching of images because it is a single image that gets broken up somehow. How does this work? Is this done using Javascript?

Comment: This is referred to as a sprite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is sprite technology in css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121357/what-is-sprite-technology-in-css)

Comment: I apologize for the duplicate. I did not know of the term "CSS Sprite" so I had no way of checking for duplicates other than a superficial description of the technique as I have seen it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is called CSS Sprites.  Search on that, but basically your intuition about how/why it works is correct!

See this SO: [css icon images or icon image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870292/css-icon-images-or-icon-image)

jQuery UI is an example of a library that uses this to excellent effect also.

Comment: Indeed, except the part about greatly helping is greatly exaggerated.  If you aren't generating the image and every position used for it in an automated fashion, you're wasting your time.

Comment: I didn't notice the "greatly" part: agreed that it's not a huge improvement, but for some sites it could be worthwhile.

Comment: Certainly, it's a sound approach, given a number of provisos.

Comment: What is the best approach to automatically generate the image and the positions?

Answer (score 1):

This article covers it:
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Pretty much, you utilize the background-position property. If you are attempting to tile a background image horizontally or vertically, this will determine your sprite sheet's orientation. (if you're not tiling any sprites, the orientation doesn't matter at all)